# Go from vertical scrolling to horizontal and then back to vertical

Tags: javascript, html, css, horizontal-scrolling, vertical-scrolling

I am creating a very long page that has a very wide SVG image in the middle of it.I basically want the page to scroll vertically until it gets to that image, and then scroll horizontally to the end of the image, and then continue scrolling vertically to the bottom of the page.

I have been researching this for hours and cannot find anything, so I would really really appreciate any suggestions. Thank you very much!

Comment: When you scroll horizontally, would the whole page move, or only the big SVG?

Comment: I'd like just the svg to move if possible, so that the page would be at the right spot when the vertical scrolling started again

Answer (score 0):

Ok this would be my solution:

Divide the page in three sections:

Upper container, SVG and the bottom container.

By default, give bottom container value "Display: none".

I would wrap the SVG to a div, giving the wrapper value "overflow: hidden;

```
<div class="svg-wrapper" style="display: none;">

    <div class="inner">

        svg or whatever image content goes here...

    </div>

</div>
```

Div 'inner' would be horizontally draggable, I would start diggin in there: http://jqueryui.com/draggable/

Then I would make event listener and when the 'inner' x value would be something else than 0, I'd set Upper contained "display: none;" so that the svg wrapper and it's contents would be the only objects visible.

When the svg would be dragged enough (x value would be -(svg width - screen width)) i'd set bottom area "disply: block;".

Does this make any sense to you?

Comment: I don't know if the draggable option is exactly what I am looking for. I'd like the SVG to scroll horizontally, not have to be dragged by the user manually. I'm looking into using this jquery: http://joelb.me/scrollpath/ but I'm having issues figuring it out

Comment: Well, the same logic applies, but you could just remove the "overflow: hidden;" value from the svg wrapper, then you'd get the horizontal scroll bar?